# WPF: Making the entire "block" of a path clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I have a special `ControlTemplate` for some of my `Button`s.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Path Name="ThePath" Fill="White" Stretch="UniformToFill" 
          Width="12" Height="12" Stroke="White"
          StrokeThickness="4" 
          Data="M1.5,1.5 L10.5,10.5 M1.5,10.5 L10.5,1.5"/>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#afa" TargetName="ThePath"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This works fine, but since I'm using a `Path` (in this case, it's just shaped like a fat X), *exactly the path* is clickable, not the small space between the corners of the X. Is there any automagic thing I can use to make the entire "block" of the X clickable?

I've considered wrapping the path in a rectangular object, but I'd just like to make sure I'm not missing something trivial.

Comment: You're not missing anything, that's how it's done (wrap in rectangle, grid, canvas, or anything with a non-null background.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aviad P. is correct.  This is what I do:

```
<Border Background="Transparent">
  <Path ... />
</Border>
```

This works because when "hit testing" to determine where a mouse click should be routed, the "Transparent" brush is considered as if it was a regular color.

Comment: One side note: It isn't necessary to actually *wrap* the path in anything, one can just use a second path in the template that comprises the shape that should be clickable and set `Fill="Transparent"` (I needed to have a circular shape clickable and didn't want to fiddle with a `Border` and `CornerRadius`, in my case).

Comment: This only worked for me when I added `IsHitTestVisible="True"` to the `Border`